# Merge two geodatabases with identical structure

Tags: spatial-database, merge, file-geodatabase

I'm using an ArcGIS addon which stores all created data (shapes and tables) in a gdb. The addon is made for single user use but to safe time I want to split the work with someone else. After that I want to merge both geodatabases into one.

Is this possible? Line segments get IDs which are referenced in the tables. So by merging, identical IDs would have to be changed - in all tables in the same way. Maybe by adding to each ID in one of geodatabases the same number, like ID=ID+1000. But I don't know how to do that in ArcGIS either. Also it seems that the merge function in the toolbox only accepts one file add a time. So I would have to merge each table seperately because I don't want to change the structure. The number of tables has to stay the same, otherwise the addon probably won't work anymore.

Is there an easy way to do this. Is this possible at all?

Robert

Answer (score 1):

you can use  [Global IDs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000014000000) to create and save IDs . If you want to save th IDs in all of locations and without any conflicts and changes, the Global ID is the best for you .

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new ID field, and populate it with your own id, starting at 1.
Your teammate do the same but starts at 1000 (for example, depending the numer of objects in your gdb).

To generate the id, open the attribute table and the field calculator, and follow the instructions given here :
http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38517

So when merging the tables, all your ids will be unique, and referenced correctly.

I can't comment your question, so what's the name of the addon you're using ?